# Class instantiation is not working

Tags: java, android

I have a class and I want to instantiate it to use its setter and getter method. But for some reasons I cann't set values from other external classes.

Here is the base class Fila.java:

```
public class Fila {

    int icon;
    String name;



    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here, I try to set values to this class:

```
public class agregar extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView lview3;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Object> itemList;
    private Fila fila;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    int img_ah;
    String nom_ah;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.principal);

        settings = getSharedPreferences(this.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);
        editor.commit();

        img_ah = settings.getInt("icono",0);
        nom_ah = settings.getString("nombre",null);

        prepareArrayLits();
        lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, itemList);
        lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
        lview3.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Fila bean = (Fila) adapter.getItem(position);

    }


    public void prepareArrayLits()
    {
        itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();
       AddObjectToList(img_ah, nom_ah);

    }


    public void AddObjectToList(int imagen, String nombre)
    {


        fila = new Fila();
        fila.setIcon(imagen);
        fila.setName(nombre);
        itemList.add(fila);
    }
}
```

And when I want to get this values nothing is showing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: and what exactly is not working ??.

Comment: You mean that itemList is empty?  What??

Comment: Hi, what's not working is the fila.setIcon(imagen) method. When I call the getIcon method is empty because the setIcon doesn't work.

Comment: Solved! the problem wasn't the class called, was the array  itemList = new ArrayList<Object>(); It had to be an Fila array and not an Object array.

Comment: I guess the real problem is that while things were being added to the list, nothing was causing the GUI to *re-render* the contents of the list. (You've also got many stylistic issues, but they aren't the key things you've got to fix here.)

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a class either to as a global private such as

```
private Fila fila = new Fila();
```

and then use that inscance in a method

```
public void foo() {
   fila.setIcon(icon);
   fila.getIcon();
}
```

or do instantiation in a method / or constructor

```
public void foo() {
   Fila fila = new Fila();

   fila.setIcon(icon);
   fila.getIcon();
}
```

Also when you have field variables please put a access modifier next to them

```
private int icon;
private String name;
```

or

```
protected int icon;
protected String name;
```

depending on what access restrictions you want on these fields

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question..

Comment: Humm... the code has all the suggestion you wrote, but doesn't work.